# Good references to start studying the curve shortening flow

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves, mean-curvature-flows

I want to study the curve shortening flow on curves in $\mathbb{R^2}$. I have knowledge of the local theory of plane and space curves (obviously that comes with linear algebra and calculus as well), but nothing as advanced as topology or anything like that. I'd appreciate some recommendations on good introductions to the topic.

*I've included the tag mean curvature flow because I'm aware the subject I want to study is a special case of the mean curvature flow.*

Comment: Try GSM-206 published by AMS.